# Ipython installation on 3.3 x64 errors

Tags: python, installation, ipython

I don't have experience in downloading libraries, so any help is appreciated. I've got a fresh install of Python3.3 and am trying to get IPython for 64bit Windows 7. The IPython .exe installer ran fine and completed normally, but I can't access the program. I looked through [their documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html), and tried the commands there, but

```
$ python setup.py install
```

returns invalid syntax, highlighting "setup". I thought the fix might be in the distribute library mentioned on the page, so I went to go try and get that first. However, using the script from [distribute's install page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions) revealed it's own errors, namely

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\distribute_setup.py", line 541, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Python33\distribute_setup.py", line 537, in main
    tarball = download_setuptools(download_base=options.download_base)
  File "C:\Python33\distribute_setup.py", line 200, in download_setuptools
    log.warn("Downloading %s", url)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\log.py", line 47, in warn
    self._log(WARN, msg, args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\log.py", line 30, in _log
    if stream.errors == 'strict':
AttributeError: errors
```

I've been at it for a couple hours now, and I'm fresh out of ideas. What next?

Comment: You did notice that "Officially, IPython requires Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, or 3.2", right? That being said, I've gotten it working with 3.3 on 64-bit Mac with no problem, just by doing `pip-3.3 install ipython`… but I can easily imagine that the py3-win-amd64 installer doesn't work with 3.3 yet.

Comment: Meanwhile, the part of `distribute` that you're having problems with seems to be downloading `setuptools`. Maybe the answer is to explicitly install that first, then install `distribute` (which you can do via `pip`).

Comment: Finally, when you say "I can't access the program", what does that mean? Is it just that `ipython` doesn't end up on your `%PATH%`, or something different?

Comment: @abarnert: No, don't try to download setuptools. distribute is the replacement for setuptools, and setuptools doesn't work on Python 3. The function is still called `download_setuptools` for historical reasons, but it's really downloading distribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you ran into [Python bug 12967](http://bugs.python.org/issue12967). You need to run `distribute_setup.py` outside of IDLE (i.e. in a command prompt).

Comment: Wow, you got it. I'm pretty new at all this, and don't I feel foolish now. Thanks!

Comment: I'll also note that the x64 installer does work with 3.3, as does everything I've played with so far from the list of libraries at [Christoph Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), though I've had yet to test most of it thoroughly.

Comment: @user1816773: No problem. If this answer solved it for you, you can accept it (click the tick mark), so the question shows up as answered.